# Как программно задать свои классы li для навигации в wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Меню html:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav col-md-6 center-block navbar-nav_main">
  <li class="active nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">...</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
```

В header.php соответственно вывожу:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array(
                   'theme_location' => 'primary',
                   'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav col-md-6 center-block navbar-nav_main',
                   'container'      => 'ul'
    ) );
  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Выводит меню со своими классами для `li` (`menu-item`), а нужен класс именно `nav-item` и для `a` нужен класс именно `nav-link`.

P.S: *Вариант через админку не предлагать. Использую bootstrap 4. Только разбираю wp.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решила вопрос с помощью `'walker'`.

**functions.php:**

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
            global $wp_query;           
            /*
             * Некоторые из параметров объекта $item
             * ID - ID самого элемента меню, а не объекта на который он ссылается
             * menu_item_parent - ID родительского элемента меню
             * classes - массив классов элемента меню
             * post_date - дата добавления
             * post_modified - дата последнего изменения
             * post_author - ID пользователя, добавившего этот элемент меню
             * title - заголовок элемента меню
             * url - ссылка
             * attr_title - HTML-атрибут title ссылки
             * xfn - атрибут rel
             * target - атрибут target
             * current - равен 1, если является текущим элементов
             * current_item_ancestor - равен 1, если текущим является вложенный элемент
             * current_item_parent - равен 1, если текущим является вложенный элемент
             * menu_order - порядок в меню
             * object_id - ID объекта меню
             * type - тип объекта меню (таксономия, пост, произвольно)
             * object - какая это таксономия / какой тип поста (page /category / post_tag и т д)
             * type_label - название данного типа с локализацией (Рубрика, Страница)
             * post_parent - ID родительского поста / категории
             * post_title - заголовок, который был у поста, когда он был добавлен в меню
             * post_name - ярлык, который был у поста при его добавлении в меню
             */
            $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

            /*
             * Генерируем строку с CSS-классами элемента меню
             */
            $class_names = $value = '';
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

            // функция join превращает массив в строку
            $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
            $class_names = ' class="nav-item"';

            /*
             * Генерируем ID элемента
             */
            $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
            $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

            /*
             * Генерируем элемент меню
             */
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

            // атрибуты элемента, title="", rel="", target="" и href=""
            $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

            // ссылка и околоссылочный текст
            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a class="nav-link"'. $attributes .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }
}
```

**header.php:**

```
  <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    'menu_class'     => 'nav navbar-nav col-md-6 center-block navbar-nav_main',
                    'container'      => 'ul',
                    'walker' => new mainMenuWalker ()
        ) );
    ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function add_classes_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
  $classes[] = 'test_class';
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_classes_on_li',1,3);
```

[Источник](http://www.wptricks24.com/add-class-li-using-wp_nav_menu/)

Можете попробовать [bs4navwalker](https://github.com/dupkey/bs4navwalker), если вам необходимо больше чем просто один класс добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть функция `wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu )`.

Пример:

```
$menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug';

if( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() && isset($locations[ $menu_name ]) ){
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] ); // получаем ID

  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu ); // получаем элементы меню

  // создаем список
  $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name .
    ' class="nav navbar-nav col-md-6 center-block navbar-nav_main"'>';

  foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ){
  $menu_list .= '<li class="nav-item"><a href="' . $menu_item->url .
    ' class="nav-link"">' . $menu_item->title . '</a></li>';
  }

  $menu_list .= '</ul>';
  }
  else 
    $menu_list = '<ul><li>Меню "' . $menu_name . '" не определено.</li></ul>';
```

Comment: кусок не до конца вырванного кода, ну да за функцию спасибо.