# Свое меню на WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Использую функцию `wp_nav_menu`
Вот код:

```
if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu'))
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'header_menu', // расположение меню в теме, вывели header_menu
            'menu_class' => 'menu__ul menu__ul-pos',
            'container' => '',
            'container_class' => '',
            'link_before' => '<li class="menu__li menu__li-pos">',
            'link_after' => '</li>',
        ));
```

Казалось бы всё хорошо, и вывод меню есть, но функция создает по 2 пункта меню.

```html
<ul id="menu-menu" class="menu__ul menu__ul-pos">
<li id="menu-item-36" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-36"><a href="/"></a></li>
<li class="menu__li menu__li-pos"><a href="/">Главная</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37"><a href="/sample-page/"></a></li>
<li class="menu__li menu__li-pos"><a href="/sample-page/">Пример страницы</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-34"><a href="/2016/10/12/mdl-website/"></a></li>
<li class="menu__li menu__li-pos"><a href="/2016/10/12/mdl-website/">MDL website</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-35"><a href="/2016/10/12/sunt-nulla/"></a></li>
<li class="menu__li menu__li-pos"><a href="/2016/10/12/sunt-nulla/">Sunt nulla</a></li>
</ul>
```

Один пункт с текстом и классами моего пункта, а второй пункт свой пустой со своими классами. Как это исправить, тк юзать классы WP не хочу.

Comment: Недавно отвечал на [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575003/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-wordpress-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e/576385#576385)   
Елена ниже ответила, что для создания своих меню необходимо юзать класс `Walker_Nav_Menu`

Comment: Я вот задавала похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567347/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-li-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Себе делала так с помощью `'walker'`:

**header.php:**

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
   <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
                          'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
                          'menu_class'     => 'nav_menu_ul',
                          'container'      => 'ul',
                          'walker' => new mainMenuWalker ()
       ) );
   ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**functions.php:**

```
class mainMenuWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;           
        /*
         * Некоторые из параметров объекта $item
         * ID - ID самого элемента меню, а не объекта на который он ссылается
         * menu_item_parent - ID родительского элемента меню
         * classes - массив классов элемента меню
         * post_date - дата добавления
         * post_modified - дата последнего изменения
         * post_author - ID пользователя, добавившего этот элемент меню
         * title - заголовок элемента меню
         * url - ссылка
         * attr_title - HTML-атрибут title ссылки
         * xfn - атрибут rel
         * target - атрибут target
         * current - равен 1, если является текущим элементов
         * current_item_ancestor - равен 1, если текущим является вложенный элемент
         * current_item_parent - равен 1, если текущим является вложенный элемент
         * menu_order - порядок в меню
         * object_id - ID объекта меню
         * type - тип объекта меню (таксономия, пост, произвольно)
         * object - какая это таксономия / какой тип поста (page /category / post_tag и т д)
         * type_label - название данного типа с локализацией (Рубрика, Страница)
         * post_parent - ID родительского поста / категории
         * post_title - заголовок, который был у поста, когда он был добавлен в меню
         * post_name - ярлык, который был у поста при его добавлении в меню
         */
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        /*
         * Генерируем строку с CSS-классами элемента меню
         */
        $class_names = $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        // функция join превращает массив в строку
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="nav-item"';

        /*
         * Генерируем ID элемента
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        /*
         * Генерируем элемент меню
         */
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        // атрибуты элемента, title="", rel="", target="" и href=""
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

        // ссылка и околоссылочный текст
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a class="nav-link"'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

*Думаю под себя сможете настроить.*